# How to remove the arrow generated in the dropmenu Bootstrap 3.3.7

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having a problem with the navbar provided by bootstrap. When using dropdown-menu it would generate an arrow up and down. how do i remove the arrow? I have search the internet but i'm still couldn't fix it.

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
     <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="navbar-header">
     <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info navbar-btn">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left"></i>
            <span></span>
     </button>
     </div>

       <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
           <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" >Menu<span class="caret"></span></a>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                 <li><a href="#">a</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">b</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">c</a></li>
               </ul>
           </li>
        </ul>
     </div>
 </nav>
```

Here is the sample picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D474p.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the `<span class="caret"></span>` or, via CSS, you could just hide it like this:

```css
.dropdown-toggle .caret {
        display:none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
     <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="navbar-header">
     <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info navbar-btn">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left"></i>
            <span></span>
     </button>
     </div>

       <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
           <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" >Menu<span class="caret"></span></a>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                 <li><a href="#">a</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">b</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">c</a></li>
               </ul>
           </li>
        </ul>
     </div>
 </nav>
```

Comment: okay the updated is still not working.. it only removes the .caret but the arrow is still there

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. Can't you remove the `<span class="caret"></span>`?

Comment: the .caret has removed because you put the css .dropdown-toggle .caret {
        display:none;
    } but the arrow from the dropdown menu is still there

Comment: what do you see if you press "run code snippet" in my answer? I don't see any arrow...

Comment: yes the run code snippet has removed the arrow, but im still getting it.. from my system. I copied all of the new bootstrap but still the same.

Comment: in your case you have another arrow coming from elsewhere in the code...

Comment: No, the arrow will appear after i click the menu.

Comment: I can't reproduce it... so I can't help further... sorry.

Comment: this is my fault... one of the line in my stylesheet is the causes of this. Btw thank you